# Why do I need an additional parseInt for this code to work property?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

From my understanding the code below converts the user input into an integer and writes it to the variable called `guess`:

`let guess = parseInt(prompt("enter number here))`

That being the case is there any point in including an additional `parseInt` in the following while loop? I ask because the code seems to break whenever I omit it.

```
while (parseInt(guess) !== targetNumber){
if (guess > targetNumber) {
    guess = prompt("Too high! Enter a new guess:");
} else {
    guess = prompt("Too low! Enter a new guess:");
}
```

Comment: Point is that in your if/else you are setting new value to `guess` from `prompt`, which will convert guess to string. And then `while` loop goes to next iteration and tries to compare string with a number if you remove parseInt in it.

Comment: You don't need two calls to `parseInt()`. If you pass a number to `parseInt()` the first thing that happens is that it's converted to a string; it's pointless. Note that your loop gets a *new* value on each iteration, and except for the code in the `while()` loop header there are no other calls to `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseInt is a method that returns number but it not change the parameter value.
while loop evaluate the parseInt of `guess` but it will now change it and prompt will assign to `guess` string, if you want only use parseInt in your case I recommand use it like this:

```js
while (guess !== targetNumber){
if (guess > targetNumber) {
    guess = parseInt(prompt("Too high! Enter a new guess:"));
} else {
    guess = parseInt(prompt("Too low! Enter a new guess:"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Because it's block scope performance.
In JavaScript if you declarat a variable with let, this is block scope.
even for same variable name in new block like while and for is a new variable name so you need use ***parseInt*** inside while loop.